# Getting cannot request a property or pattern that is not cached error

Tags: c#, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I'm trying to get all properties of an automation element present at specific point on desktop or
which currently have mouse focus using UI Automation C# API. For this, I am using GetPhysicalCursorPos(out pt) to get the co-ordinates for selected element and FromPoint method of AutomationElement to retrieves a new AutomationElement object for the UI item at specified point on the desktop. But , I am getting error as "Cannot request a property or pattern that is not cached" for each property of that element. I am trying this with Calculator.

Here is the test code...

```
    public static void GetElements(System.Drawing.Point pt)
    {
        CachePropertiesWithScope(AutomationElement.RootElement);
        AutomationElement ae = ElementFromCursor(pt);
    }
    private static void CachePropertiesWithScope(AutomationElement elementMain)
    {
        AutomationElement elementList = null;
        CacheRequest c = new CacheRequest();
        c.Add(AutomationElement.NameProperty);
        c.Add(AutomationElement.IsEnabledProperty);
        c.Add(SelectionItemPattern.Pattern);
        c.Add(SelectionItemPattern.SelectionContainerProperty);
        c.TreeScope = TreeScope.Element | TreeScope.Children;
        using (c.Activate())
        {
            elementList =
        elementMain.FindFirst(
          TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(
    AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Calculator"));
        }
    }
    private static AutomationElement ElementFromCursor(System.Drawing.Point pt)
    {
        AutomationElement element = null;
        // Convert mouse position from System.Drawing.Point to System.Windows.Point.
        System.Windows.Point point = new System.Windows.Point(pt.X, pt.Y);
        element = AutomationElement.FromPoint(point);
        return element;
    }`
```

Any thoughts on what I may be missing here or what I am doing wrong??

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to do here. You're activating a cache request on `elementList`, but you're not using it at all. After the cached properties and patterns have been pushed, you could read, e.g., `elementList.Cached.Name`. Note that the Condition is most probably wrong, I don't remember that Window exposing an `AutomationId`; the Condition could be `new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Calculator")`, or `ClassNameProperty` set to `CalcFrame`. -- This appear to be a dynamic selector, so caching patterns  or properties of an element doesn't seem that useful.

Comment: Hi, I have tried PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Calculator") too, but getting the same error. Also, am not using cache request on elementlist , because it contains the same error that is "Getting cannot request a property or pattern that is not cached error" for cachedParent and for other's too.